# PowerPacks namespace error in visual studio express 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone, winapi

I am trying to build a project in Visual Studio 2012 and i get this error

```
The type or namespace name 'PowerPacks' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    Error   7   The type or namespace name 'PowerPacks' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I have added the reference for PowerPacks,but still getting this error.
How shall i overcome this.

Comment: Did you add `using PowerPacks;` on your code ?

Comment: Or `using Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks;` ?

Comment: yes i have added that too...but it still doesn't build

Comment: tried both..still gives the same error

Comment: I see you have the `windows-phone` tag.  I'm pretty sure that this means that you can't use PowerPacks on a Windows Phone.

Comment: @Bobson:since i am a beginner,i didnt know that we cannot use powerpacks for windows phone....thanks

Comment: @AmanAgarwal - I added it as an answer instead of a comment.  You can click the green checkmark next to it to indicate that it's the answer which answered your question.  Welcome to Stack Overflow, and good luck with your learning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Elaborated on, from my comment:*

Usually when this happens, and it can't be resolved by adding the reference, it means that the type of project you're using is incompatible with the type of the reference.  This bites me a lot with the ".NET 4 Client Profile" vs the ".NET 4 Profile".

I suspect that the problem you're running into, based on your `windows-phone` tag, is that the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks` library is based on `Windows.Form`, which is not available on the phone.  Thus, anything which would need it, like PowerPacks, is going to be incompatible with a phone project.

I can't point you to an equivalent library for the phone, but I wouldn't be surprised if there's already the functionality you want built into the phone libraries.